# factory_bot add two or more associations in create method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have a `user` model with many accounts.

In my test I want to use factory_bot to create `user` with two or more `accounts`

Currently I can do it by making a user and two accounts separately via factory_bot, then adding the accounts after like this:

```
@user = create(:user)

#Create two Accounts
@account_1 = create(:account)
@account_2 = create(:account)


#Add accounts to User
@user.accounts << @account_1
@user.accounts << @account_2
```

I'd ideally like to set it up like this or similar:

```
@user = create(:user, accounts: [@account_1, @account_2])
```

I need access to account for other models set up later.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with FactoryBot's [transient_attributes](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/main/GETTING_STARTED.md#transient-attributes), so set up your factory like this:

```rb
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do
    firstName { Faker::Name.first_name }
    lastName { Faker::Name.last_name  }
    # etc

    transient do
      accounts {[]}
    end

    after(:create) do |user, evaluator|
      user.accounts << evaluator.accounts
    end
  end
end
```

and you can create the user by:

```rb
FactoryBot.create(:user, accounts: [FactoryBot.create(:account), FactoryBot.create(:account)])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `accounts_count` transient attribute

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :account do
    # some account attributes

    user
  end

  factory :user do
    # some user attributes

    factory :user_with_accounts do
      transient do
        accounts_count { 2 }
      end

      accounts do
        Array.new(accounts_count) { association(:account) }
      end
    end
  end
end

@user = create(:user_with_accounts)
@account1, @account2 = @user.accounts

create(:user_with_accounts, accounts_count: 5).accounts.size # 5
build(:user_with_accounts, accounts_count: 5).accounts.size # 5
build_stubbed(:user_with_accounts, accounts_count: 5).accounts.size # 5
```